# HttpClient PutAsync causes 409 conflict on invoking salesforce api

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, salesforce, httpclient

I try to invoke a Salesforce REST API where I do a `PUT` operation. If I use the same URL with headers and body content in the Postman tool, I am able to do the `PUT` operation without any issues. When I try from my local machine using C#, it always throws a 409 Conflict error.

I am stuck with this issues for a day. Any help would be appreciated

```
finalResponse = await client.PutAsync(
    strDynamicUrl,
    new StringContent(strRequestBody)).ConfigureAwait(false);
finalResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

Just to be sure if my data is wrong: I tried with minimal data like only passing one parameter like "Name" (which is valid for my case) for the `PUT` operation. But even this gets the same error 409 from C# while it is successful from Postman.

Comment: Are the headers indeed identical?

Comment: Yes the request , url as well has the header are identical

Comment: What's in the response body ?